# GCC __attribute__((aligned(4))) not working as expected

Tags: c, alignment, sparc

I have a GCC question about variable alignment. I thought I understood it, but can't get this to work.
This code:

```
uint8 aaa[4];
uint32 *bbb = (uint32 *)&aaa;
```

generates this warning:

```
warning: cast increases required alignment of target type [-Wcast-align]
  175 |     uint32 *bbb = (uint32 *)&aaa;
```

I've tried several combinations of the aligned() attribute none of which work:

```
__attribute__((aligned(4))) uint8 aaa[4];
uint8 aaa[4] __attribute__((aligned(4)));
```

This method fixes it, but it's too ugly (actually the real code is nested structures and adding unions would be difficult):

```
union {
    uint8 aaa[4];
    uint32 bbb;
} aaa2;
uint32 *bbb2 = (uint32 *)&aaa2;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's ugly, hide it in a macro.

Comment: *none of which work* - doesn't work how?

Comment: Is this a global array or automatic/local? This attribute does not work for stack-allocated variables

Comment: FWIW, the union method is an "official" alternative to the attribute as per the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes)

Comment: Doesn’t work as in it doesn’t fix the warning.

Comment: This is a stack variable. Hmm, I thought I read that it didn’t used to work, like 20 years ago, but it does now. I would think if the union is an alternative, and works, that both would.